# The limit of a sequence that doesn't have a limit?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$$s_n=\frac{n+(-1)^n}{n-(-1)^n}$$

Does this sequence have a limit? I know that $(-1)^n$ does not have a limit, but if we think like whether $(-1)^n$ is positive or negative, n gets infinitely large, so 1/1 is 1?

I am just not sure about this...

Comment: Perhaps you could do something like
$$
n -1 \leq n \pm (-1)^n  \leq n +1
$$
and then show that $s_n$ is between such and such expressions ...

Comment: And perhaps you could divide numerator and denominator by $n$

Comment: If $n$ tends to $\infty$, $s_n$ tends to $1$ , which you easily see if you divide numerator and denominaotr by $n$. That $(-1)^n$ has no limit does not matter here.

Comment: You intuition is correct For rigourous proof, just factor out $n$ in the numerator and in the denominator.

Answer (score 2):

It's clearer if you write $$s_n = \frac{n+(-1)^n}{n-(-1)^n}=\frac{1 + \frac{(-1)^n}{n}}{1 - \frac{(-1)^n}{n}}$$

after diving both numerator and denominator by $n$...

As $|\frac{(-1)^n}{n}| = \frac1n$ it's clear that those two terms tend to $0$.

What remains is $\frac{1+0}{1-0} = 1$.